# JavaScript: Code-Selection - What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, selection

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Select Code</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      function selectCode(a) {

        // Get ID of Code Block
        var e = a.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('code')[0];

        // Not IE or IE9+
        if (window.getSelection) {
          var s = window.getSelection();
          if (s.setBaseAndExtent) {
            s.setBaseAndExtent(e, 0, e, e.innerText.length - 1);
          }

          // Firefox and Opera
          else {
            if (window.opera && e.innerHTML.substring(e.innerHTML.length - 4) == '<br>') {
              e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML + '&nbsp;';
            }
            var r = document.createRange();
            r.selectNodeContents(e);
            s.removeAllRanges();
            s.addRange(r);
          }
        }

        // Some older browsers
        else if (document.getSelection) {
          var s = document.getSelection();
          var r = document.createRange();
          r.selectNodeContents(e);
          s.removeAllRanges();
          s.addRange(r);
        }

        // IE
        else if (document.selection) {
          var r = document.body.createTextRange();
          r.moveToElementText(e);
          r.select();
        }
      };
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a onclick="selectCode(this); return false;" href="#">Select all</a>
  <code>Some Code</code>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong? It just doesn't work. :-(

Comment: "It just doesn't work" doesn't help anybody to assist you with the problem. **How** does it not work?  Are there errors in the console?  What do you expect to happen that doesn't?  What have you tried so far to debug the problem?

Comment: Which part "doesn't work"?

Comment: The `selectCode` function only exists inside the `window.onload`, it doesn't exist anywhere else.

Comment: Many SO users downvote questions that have not enough details to provide you a detailed answer. To avoid this, it is wise (and helpful for all others) to add eg. a little description, what the code is supposed to do. And if you provide a www.jsfiddle.net example, everybody can easily test your code and find possible error messages in browser's console.

Comment: It works in Chrome. Which browser is the issue

Comment: @hop: It doesn't work for me in Chrome.  Are you using the code as-is, or are you just testing the method separately?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sorry I had to remove the window.onload. I have added it as an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed the window.onload

See the working code here http://jsfiddle.net/5n4cw/

```
<a onclick="selectCode(this);" href="#">Select all</a>
<code>Some Code</code>


<script type='text/javascript'>

 function selectCode(a) {

        // Get ID of Code Block
        var e = a.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('code')[0];
        // Not IE or IE9+
        if (window.getSelection) {
          var s = window.getSelection();
          if (s.setBaseAndExtent) {
            s.setBaseAndExtent(e, 0, e, e.innerText.length - 1);
          }

          // Firefox and Opera
          else {
            if (window.opera && e.innerHTML.substring(e.innerHTML.length - 4) == '<br>') {
              e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML + '&nbsp;';
            }
            var r = document.createRange();
            r.selectNodeContents(e);
            s.removeAllRanges();
            s.addRange(r);
          }
        }

        // Some older browsers
        else if (document.getSelection) {
          var s = document.getSelection();
          var r = document.createRange();
          r.selectNodeContents(e);
          s.removeAllRanges();
          s.addRange(r);
        }

        // IE
        else if (document.selection) {
          var r = document.body.createTextRange();
          r.moveToElementText(e);
          r.select();
        }
      }

</script>
```

Comment: It only works with one code section. If there are more, only the first one is selected. How to fix this?

Comment: That's because you are doing it only on [0]. Instead of a.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('code')[0], take the entire object array and iterate over it

Comment: But have a look at this: http://www.camp-firefox.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=75674&start=195 There are two code sections and it works with the same JavaScript.